# Pygame won't import to python

Tags: python, pygame

When i type import pygame, i get an error that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Does anybody know what this means?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you need to look at `pygame\base.pyd` in Dependency Walker and see which DLL it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

I made this mistake too. The problem is that you are using the Idle Shell to attempt to build a Python program. Here is how I get out of the shell:

1. Save the Idle Shell as a .py in a location of your choice
2. Afterward, find the .py you created.
3. Left click, then Right click to display the context submenu (the menu with copy/paste)
4. Select "Edit with Idle"
5. This will open the .py file in the Editor Window. Delete all extra content to create a blank screen
6. Now you can import your modules and begin programming:

   ```
   import os, sys
   import pygame
   from pygame.locals import *
   [...]
   ```

This will give you the head start to work with pygame.

Answer (score 0):

This question at Game Developement (another Stack Exchange Site) should answer your question:
[Installing the right version of PyGame](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56595/installing-the-right-version-of-pygame)
This user can't make Python to know that PyGame is there so he asks that question. His question should be similar to yours, making it convinient for you. I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt, write `pip install pygame` if you have a Windows PC, or `pip3 install pygame` if you have Linux or MacOS.

Comment: Seem not is the error of no installation, since the error message: `site-packages\pygame\...``, that prove installed already.